# Write Regression summary to the csv file in R

Tags: r, csv, regression

I have data on revenue of a company from sales of various products (csv files), one of which looks like the following:

```
> abc
   Order.Week..BV. Product.Number Quantity Net.ASP Net.Price
1         2013-W44        ABCDEF       92  823.66       749
2         2013-W44        ABCDEF       24  898.89       749
3         2013-W44        ABCDEF      243  892.00       749
4         2013-W45        ABCDEF       88  796.84       699
5         2013-W45        ABCDEF       18  744.80       699
```

Now, I'm fitting a multiple regression model with Net.Price as Y and Quantity, Net.ASP as x1 and x2. There are more than 100 such files and I'm trying to do it using the following code:

```
fileNames <- Sys.glob("*.csv")

for (fileName in fileNames) {      

abc <- read.csv(fileName, header = TRUE, sep = ",")

fit <- lm(Net.Price ~ Quantity + Net.ASP, data = abc)

x <- data.frame (abc, summary(fit))

write.csv (x, file = fileName)

}
```

Now, I understand the line `x <- data.frame (abc, summary(fit))` is wrong, as it's saying `Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) :   cannot coerce class ""summary.lm"" to a data.frame` ,but I want to write the summary of regression model for each csv file to the file itself. Please help.

Comment: What exact part of the summary you want to add to the data.frame? 
`summary` returns lots of "garbage" that can't be coerced to a vector, unless you will transform it to a `list`

Comment: I want all the estimates, R square and p value. At least, all the estimates will do

Comment: In order to get the estimates you can do `x <- cbind(abc, t(as.numeric(coefficients(fit))));
names(x)[(length(x) - 2):length(x)] <- names(coefficients(fit))`

Comment: Not working. Showing the folloeing `Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
  cannot open file 'A3G47AV.csv': Permission denied`

Comment: This error has nothing to with my code. It works with the data you've provided

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provided your data set and your comments, I would do something like

```
abc <- read.table(text = "
Order.Week..BV.    Product.Number    Quantity    Net.ASP    Net.Price
1         2013-W44        ABCDEF       92  823.66       749
2         2013-W44        ABCDEF       24  898.89       749
3         2013-W44        ABCDEF      243  892.00       749
4         2013-W45        ABCDEF       88  796.84       699
5         2013-W45        ABCDEF       18  744.80       699", header = T) # Yor data

fit <- lm(Net.Price ~ Quantity + Net.ASP, data = abc)
x <- cbind(abc, t(as.numeric(coefficients(fit))), t(as.numeric(summary(fit)$coefficients[, 4])), summary(fit)$r.squared)
names(x)[(length(x) - 6):length(x)] <- c(paste("coeff", names(coefficients(fit))), paste("P-value", names(summary(fit)$coefficients[, 4])), "R-squared")
```

Which will return

```
  Order.Week..BV. Product.Number Quantity Net.ASP Net.Price coeff (Intercept) coeff Quantity coeff Net.ASP P-value (Intercept) P-value Quantity
1        2013-W44         ABCDEF       92  823.66       749          434.0829    0.001853692     0.3545852          0.09474093        0.9898202
2        2013-W44         ABCDEF       24  898.89       749          434.0829    0.001853692     0.3545852          0.09474093        0.9898202
3        2013-W44         ABCDEF      243  892.00       749          434.0829    0.001853692     0.3545852          0.09474093        0.9898202
4        2013-W45         ABCDEF       88  796.84       699          434.0829    0.001853692     0.3545852          0.09474093        0.9898202
5        2013-W45         ABCDEF       18  744.80       699          434.0829    0.001853692     0.3545852          0.09474093        0.9898202
  P-value Net.ASP R-squared
1       0.1865054 0.7165826
2       0.1865054 0.7165826
3       0.1865054 0.7165826
4       0.1865054 0.7165826
5       0.1865054 0.7165826
```

Comment: It wroks now. The error was due to wrong specification of path.

Answer (score 9):

You can write to the text file very easily using

```
sink("summary.txt")
summary(lm)
sink()
```

Comment: I thought about that. But here I've more than 100 csv files, each with different name. Will that work here?

Comment: yes, do you want to save all of them in one file?? you ca definitely do that. or if u want to save in 100 different txt files corresponding to .csv files you create a filename using the csv name. for example fname<-paste("summary","abc.csv");sink(fname);summary(lm);sink()