# How to export coefficients of the regression analysis fto a spreadsheet or csv file?

Tags: r, excel, csv, regression

I am new to RStudio and I guess my question is pretty easy to solve but a lot of searching did not help me.

I am running a regression and `summary(regression1)` shows me all the coefficients and so on. 
Now I am using `coef(regression1)` so it only gives me the coefficients which I want to export to a file.

`write.csv(coef, file="regression1.csv)` and the `"Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) : cannot coerce class ""function"" to a data.frame"` occurs.

Would be great If you could help me. I am searching the web for a few hours now and was not successful.

Do I have to change `coef` somehow so it fits in a data.frame?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I'd suggest trying `write.csv(as.data.frame(summary(regression1)$coef), file="regression1.csv)`

Comment: Thank you very much! It works. Just one thing left: every information is in different columns but always in one cell. How may I change that?

Comment: It looks like this: [link]http://abload.de/image.php?img=screenshotmushj.jpg [/link]

Would be great to separate the values to A2 B2 C2 D2 etc.

Comment: Possibly you need to use `write.csv2`. Otherwise you need to take care to import the data correctly to Excel (e.g., specify the column seperator in Excel). That's not an R problem.

Comment: For folks dealing with (not too large) sparse matrices, this may work:
write.csv(as.data.frame(as.matrix(Y)), row.names = T, file ='F:/testY.csv')

...not pRetty...

Comment: The solution posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24527116/write-regression-summary-to-the-csv-file-in-r) is much easier.

Comment: @Roland I need `coefficient` and `Pr`.

Answer (score 37):

There's a contributed package called [`broom`](https://github.com/dgrtwo/broom) that simplifies this task, it converts model output to tidy dataframes. Here's a self-contained reproducible example:

Download and install the package:

```
library(devtools)
install_github("dgrtwo/broom")
library(broom)
```

Here's the normal base output, not very convenient:

```
lmfit <- lm(mpg ~ wt, mtcars)
lmfit

Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           wt  
     37.285       -5.344
```

Here's the same model output after it's been tidied up by the `broom` package, much nicer and easier to work with:

```
tidy_lmfit <- tidy(lmfit)
tidy_lmfit
         term  estimate std.error statistic      p.value
1 (Intercept) 37.285126  1.877627 19.857575 8.241799e-19
2          wt -5.344472  0.559101 -9.559044 1.293959e-10
```

And here's how you'd write that dataframe to CSV:

```
write.csv(tidy_lmfit, "tidy_lmfit.csv")
```

Comment: Is this the same package that I get when I install `broom` from CRAN?

Comment: Yes, same package

Comment: Ah, very good, thanks!  In this case one can remove the reference to the github account, right?