# Transfer regression output to a .cvs or .txt table

Tags: r, output, regression, linear-regression, export-to-csv

I am trying to export the output of my regression model into a .txt or .csv file. I was able to export the main information from summary() the terms (e.g., intercept), p-values etc. However, the exported file does not give me residuals standard information, R2 and F statistics, which appears at the bottom of the output.

**Here is the code that I am using**
 `model = lm(cs~group + sex, data = metadata) #adjusting for sex.`

**Output**

> Call: lm(formula = cs ~ group + sex, data = metadata)
>
> Residuals:
>       Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
>   -16.917  -7.733  -2.506   6.934  32.494
>
> Coefficients:
>                    Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)     (Intercept)        14.051      3.767   3.731 0.000555 *** groupHFD           -3.987      4.853  -0.822 0.415880     groupHFD +Exe       1.571      4.853   0.324 0.747817     groupHFD+Exe+Gen    4.874      4.989   0.977 0.334131     groupHFD+Gen       -1.189      4.853  -0.245 0.807610     sexMale             9.633      3.104   3.103 0.003378
>
>   --- Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
>
> Residual standard error: 10.85 on 43 degrees of freedom Multiple
>   R-squared:  0.2286,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.139  F-statistic: 2.549 on
>   5 and 43 DF,  p-value: 0.04168

`#Save the regression output as table in cvs table. 
write.table(csregression, file = 'csregression.csv', sep = ",", row.names = F, col.names = T)`

**The .csv file shows the following**

> ```
>                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)     (Intercept)        14.051      3.767   3.731 0.000555  groupHFD
> ```
>
> -3.987      4.853  -0.822 0.415880     groupHFD +Exe       1.571      4.853   0.324 0.747817     groupHFD+Exe+Gen    4.874      4.989   0.977 0.334131     groupHFD+Gen       -1.189      4.853  -0.245 0.807610     sexMale             9.633      3.104   3.103 0.003378

Does someone experience the same issue? How could I export the information missing, the F-statistic and R-squared information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value returned by `lm` is an object which can be further processed using `summary`. From the value returned by `summary` you want to access `$coefficients`.

```
mod <- lm(cs~group + sex, data = metadata)
coefs <- summary(mod)$coefficients

# Write to disk with row and colnames (col.names = NA)
write.table(coefs, file="coefficients.csv", sep = ",", col.names=NA)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out the [broom](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/index.html) package. You can use it for transferring regression output to csv as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26866839/how-to-export-coefficients-of-the-regression-analysis-fto-a-spreadsheet-or-csv-f)