# How can I save output of a regression in CSV by using R

Tags: r, regression

I am using below code where I have more than 100 intercepts and coefficient. I want to save the output in excel format. Kindly help how can I do the same in R

```
df = read.csv(file.choose(), header = T)
prediction=list()
for(i in names(df)[1:ncol(df)-1]){
  prediction[[i]] =lm(get(i) ~ NYSE.Close, df)
}
prediction
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26866839/how-to-export-coefficients-of-the-regression-analysis-fto-a-spreadsheet-or-csv-f

Answer (score 1):

```r
## set up variable names
vars <- setdiff(names(mtcars), "mpg")
## set up 2-column matrix to hold results
res <- matrix(NA, nrow = length(vars), ncol = 2,
     dimnames = list(vars, c("intercept", "slope")))
for (v in vars) {
   ff <- reformulate(v, response = "mpg")  ## set up formula
   cc <- coef(lm(ff, mtcars))              ## run regression/get coefficients
   res[v, ] <- cc                          ## store coefficients
}
write.csv(res, "regression.csv")
```

If you want to be fancy/tidy:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
res <- (vars
   %>% setNames(vars) ## self-name (for .id downstream)
   %>% map(reformulate, response = "mpg")  ## create formulas
   %>% map(lm, data = mtcars)              ## run lm()
   %>% map_dfr(tidy, .id = "var")          ## extract coefs → tibble
)
write.csv(vars, "regr.csv")
```

This produces a different format: you should see which you prefer.